# How to disable `onAppear` method of a parent View?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to make a timer app and I want to know how to disable `onApear` method of a parent View or any way to solve a problem I have now.

When I navigate to a detailed view from a parent view(ListView) using `Binding` value, the `onAppear` method work, and then the `Binding` value gets be reset in case of my codes.

If I don't use a method(`func setTimer()` in my codes) to initialize ListRow in `onAppear` the binding values work well, but I can't show the initial time values when I see the first view.

How cloud I solve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

TimerApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TimerApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var timeManager = TimeManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ListTimerView()
                .environmentObject(timeManager)
        }
    }
}
```

TimeManager.swift

```
import SwiftUI

class TimeManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var multipleTimers:[MultipleTimer] = [
        MultipleTimer( hourSelection: 0, minSelection: 2, secSelection: 0),
        MultipleTimer( hourSelection: 0, minSelection: 0, secSelection: 30),
        MultipleTimer( hourSelection: 1, minSelection: 30, secSelection: 0)

    ]
    
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.05, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
}

enum TimeFormat {
    case hr
    case min
    case sec
}

enum TimerStatus {
    case running
    case pause
    case stopped
}

struct MultipleTimer:Hashable {
    var hourSelection: Int
    var minSelection: Int
    var secSelection: Int
}
```

ListTimerView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTimerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var timeManager:TimeManager
    
    @State var isAddSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(){
            VStack{
                ForEach(timeManager.multipleTimers, id:\.self){multipleTimer in
                    ListTimerRow(hourSelection: multipleTimer.hourSelection, minSelection:  multipleTimer.minSelection, secSelection:  multipleTimer.secSelection)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ListTimerRow.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTimerRow: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var timeManager:TimeManager
    
    @State var hourSelection: Int
    @State var minSelection: Int
    @State var secSelection: Int
    
    @State var duration: Double = 0
    @State var maxValue: Double = 0
    
    @State var displayedTimeFormat: TimeFormat = .min
    @State var timerStatus: TimerStatus = .stopped
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination:DetailTimerView(
            hourSelection: $hourSelection, minSelection: $minSelection, secSelection: $secSelection,
            duration:$duration, displayedTimeFormat:$displayedTimeFormat
        )){
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text(self.displayTimer())
                        .font(.title)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "stop.circle.fill")
                        .font(.title)
                        .opacity(self.timerStatus == .stopped ? 0.1 : 1)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if timerStatus != .stopped {
                                self.stop()
                            }
                        }
                    Image(systemName: self.timerStatus == .running ? "pause.circle.fill" : "play.circle.fill")
                        .font(.title)
                        .opacity(self.hourSelection == 0 && self.minSelection == 0 && self.secSelection == 0 ? 0.1 : 1)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if timerStatus == .stopped {
                                self.setTimer()
                            }
                            if duration != 0 && timerStatus != .running {
                                self.start()
                            } else if timerStatus == .running {
                                self.pause()
                            }
                        }
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(){
            self.setTimer()
            print("onAppear checked")
        }
        .onReceive(timeManager.timer) { _ in
            guard self.timerStatus == .running else { return }
            
            if self.duration > 0 {
                self.duration -= 0.05
            } else {
                self.timerStatus = .stopped
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func setTimer() {
        duration = Double(hourSelection * 3600 + minSelection * 60 + secSelection)
        maxValue = duration
        
        if duration < 60 {
            displayedTimeFormat = .sec
        } else if duration < 3600 {
            displayedTimeFormat = .min
        } else {
            displayedTimeFormat = .hr
        }
    }
    
    func displayTimer() -> String {
        
        let hr = Int(duration) / 3600
        let min = Int(duration) % 3600 / 60
        let sec = Int(duration) % 3600 % 60
        switch displayedTimeFormat {
        case .hr:
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec)
        case .min:
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
        case .sec:
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
            
        }
    }
    
    func start() {
        timerStatus = .running
    }
    
    func pause() {
        timerStatus = .pause
    }
    
    func stop() {
        timerStatus = .stopped
        duration = maxValue
    }
}
```

DetailTimerView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailTimerView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var timeManager:TimeManager
    
    @Binding var hourSelection: Int
    @Binding var minSelection: Int
    @Binding var secSelection: Int
    
    @Binding var duration: Double
    
    @Binding var displayedTimeFormat: TimeFormat
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.displayTimer())
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
    
    func displayTimer() -> String {
        
        let hr = Int(duration) / 3600
        let min = Int(duration) % 3600 / 60
        let sec = Int(duration) % 3600 % 60
        
        switch displayedTimeFormat {
        case .hr:
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec)
        case .min:
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
        case .sec:
            return String(format: "%02d:%02d", min, sec)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Can you narrow it down, so it's more specific?

Comment: @pawello2222, I need to use `self.setTimer()` but when navivate to `DetailTimerView` after a timer run the binding value in `DetailTimerView` gets reset.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the onAppear but need to set your state's initial values in an init method similar to my below example:

```
self._duration = State(initialValue: initialDurationValue)
```

For example, the init method of your ListTimerRow may be like below and you will not need to call setTimer method in onAppear.

```
init () {
    let d = Double(hourSelection * 3600 + minSelection * 60 + secSelection)
    _duration = State(initialValue: d)
    _maxValue = State(initialValue: d)
    
    if d < 60 {
        displayedTimeFormat = State(initialValue: .sec)
    } else if d < 3600 {
        displayedTimeFormat = State(initialValue: .min)
    } else {
        displayedTimeFormat = State(initialValue: .hr)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any way to use the whole `setTimer()` method without using `onAppear` method?

Comment: Thank you for your update, I finally solved it as the answer I post. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I tried some solutions and finally, I choose this way

```
  .onAppear(){
        if timerStatus == .stopped {
            self.setTimer()
        }
    }
```